# Использование флага в процедурах 'WITH RECOMPILE'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Привет . 
Можно на практических примерах показать инсткукции когда нужно принудительно делать RECOMPILE для процедуры ? 
Буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственная причина делать Recompile (вызовом `sp_recompile`) - это когда текущий скопмилированный план вас не устраивает.

Единственная реальная причина, по которой план вас может не устривать - сработавший механизм parameters sniffing - компиляция процедуры под набор параметров, переданных ей при первом вызове. Вредные случаи Parameters sniffing чинятся

- parameter hiding - перекладываением параметров в локальные переменные перед использованием (олдскульный способ).
- добавлением хинтов `OPTIMIZE FOR` - например, `OPTIMIZE FOR (@parameter UNKNOWN)`.

Любой из способов убирает необходимость в ручной (`sp_recompile`) или постоянной (`WITH RECOMPILE`, `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`) рекомпиляции.

Так что для Recompile остается только одно применение - быстрого костыля, на время пока вчитываешься в кривой план и думаешь "omg, какие еще nested loops, там же миллион записей, продакшн уже час тормозит, почему алерты не сработали, apdex же ниже плинтуса, вроде ж статистика должна была пересчитаться, какого черта там estimated rows 3, чего оно полезло в этот индекс, что за индусы писали оптимизатор, если это для него plan good enough, куда поставить хинты?).

Причин же для использования `WITH RECOMPILE` нет. Совсем.

Хорошая длинная статья о рекомпияции на английском - [Parameter Sniffing, Embedding, and the RECOMPILE Options](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options).